# Centering an image on page, the entire div is becoming a link?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image on the page. I am using this:

```css
#logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
  display: block;
  margin: 55px auto;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

#logo img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
      <a href="http://sapsrp.x10.bz/">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="SAPS Logo">
      </a>
</div>
```

I want JUST the logo to be link, not the empty space next to it. What I mean, [here](http://sapsrp.x10.bz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust your CSS like this. You need to specify the width of the image

```css
#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 55px auto;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

#logo img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a href="http://sapsrp.x10.bz/">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="SAPS Logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css with these rules bellow

```
#logo {
    text-align:center;
}

#logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 55px auto;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/za5cgfLw/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain giving no size to the image you could remove the  tag and alter the  tag like this.

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="SAPS Logo" onclick='window.location="http://sapsrp.x10.bz/"'>
```

This is a slight hack as the user will not be able to right click to open the image in a new tab. Note, you will also need to give the img tag the cursor:pointer style

Answer (score 0):

```css
#logo {
  text-align: center;
}
#logo a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 55px auto;
}
#logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

#logo img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a href="http://sapsrp.x10.bz/">
    <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" alt="SAPS Logo">
  </a>
</div>
```